# how can I implement this design element?

Tags: android

I have this design

[image]

**how can I add this effect ??**
can give an example of this implementation

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Are you using a SlidingDrawer?

Comment: Are you talking about that shadow?

Comment: No I do not use SlidingDrawer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really simple method to draw that shadow is to use a custom `ViewGroup`(the one that is in your layout) and override its `dispatchDraw` method to draw a `GradientDrawable`. For example, use a custom `ListView`:

```
public class RightShadowList extends ListView {

    private GradientDrawable mGradientShadow = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, new int[] {
                    Color.WHITE, Color.GRAY });;
    // implement the constructors

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        mGradientShadow.setBounds(getMeasuredWidth() - 5, 0,
                getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
        mGradientShadow.draw(canvas);
    }

}
```

Comment: how to do it for ListFragment?

Comment: @MaxUsanin Well a `ListFragment` is based on a single `ListView` element so override the `onCreateView` method of the `ListFragment` and return a view(or inflate a layout) which has the custom `ListView` from my answer with the id `android.R.id.list`(or for the xml layout, `@android:id/list`).

Comment: difficult to understand I do not have as much experience, need an example

Comment: @MaxUsanin See this sample https://gist.github.com/6485ceea5828fe810835 .